# IN Operator in Javascript functions like the one in SQL

Tags: javascript, in-operator

I have tried the following but it's throwing an exception:

```
                if (!$get('sslot_hf0').value in ('X', 'Y', 'Z', '0')) {
                $get('sslot_hf0').value = 'X';
            }
```

I am looking for a function similar to the `IN` operator in `SQL`

Comment: use of `in` operator in javascript. I am not sure if the ones you want to achieve can be done with this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: For the sake of completness, `in` in JavaScript is used to test whether a property exists in an Object. Things are further complicated by the fact that JavaScript arrays are actually specialised objects, so using `in` with an array is valid, but probably not what you have in mind. It tests whether something is a valid property of the array object, but not whether it is an existing value in the array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below function for the same purpose, second param can be array or object and first param is value you are searching in array or object.

```
   function inStruct(val,structure)
        {

          for(a in structure)
             {
               if(structure[a] == val)
                 {
                   return true;
                 }
             }
           return false;
        }
if(inStruct('Z',['A','B','Z']))
    {
       //do your stuff
    }
```

// this function traverse through inherited properties also

i.e in some where your included js libraries

```
Array.prototype.foo = 10;
```

than

```
 instruct(10,[1,2,3]) // will return true
```

same will happen for objects also. check this fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/rQ8AH/17/

**EDITED ::**

thank you all for comments ... this is the updated code, I thought it is better to keep old function also. so, some one can notice the difference.

```
function inStruct(val,structure)
    {

      for(a in structure)
         {

           if(structure[a] == val && structure.hasOwnProperty(a))
             {
               return true;
             }
         }
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is the best replacement till now, the other answers may works but the browser compatibility is a major. Thnaks @rupesh-patel

Comment: If the Array prototype has other properties this code may have unexpected results.

Comment: @sachleen, would you please clarify what do you mean by other properties.

Comment: `console.log(inStruct('T',['A','B','Z'])); Array.prototype.foo = 'T'; console.log(inStruct('T',['A','B','Z']));` - will return `false` (expected), `true` (unexpected)

Comment: You're right @sachleen, using "for ...in" with array iteration is a bad idea, I have walked through [this question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) 
one solution is to replace the `inStruct` with the following :

`function inStruct(val,structure)`
    `{`
     `for(var i = 0; i < structure.length; i += 1)`
         `{`
           `if(structure[i] == val)`
             `{`
               `return true;`
             `}`
         `}`
       `return false;`
    `}`

Thanks for your contribution sachleen , I hope @Rupesh updates this answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
['X', 'Y', 'Z', '0'].indexOf('Z')
> 2
['X', 'Y', 'Z', '0'].indexOf('T')
> -1

if (['X', 'Y', 'Z', '0'].indexOf($get('sslot_hf0').value) !== -1) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: It gives you the algorithm to include in your pages for that very reason :)

Comment: @sachleen, thanks for your answer, it seems that `indexof` is a good replacement for `IN` functionality like in `SQL`, however, the code you used is throwing an exception `$get is not defined`, do you have explanation why `indexof` is not recognizing the '$get' function?

Comment: That's your code, not mine. See the first two lines and the doc for usage of the function. If `$get` is not defined here, it's not defined in your question's code either.

Comment: @sachleen, I thought it's related to the `IndexOf` that's why i asked you, however, it's not related,

Answer (score 2):

SQL:

```
something in ('X','Y','Z','0')
```

Modern JavaScript (including IE>8):

```
['X','Y','Z','0'].indexOf(something)>-1
```

More Modern JavaScript (!IE):

```
['X','Y','Z','0'].includes(something)
```

If you need a simple `includes` polyfill for legacy browsers (including IE):

```
if(!Array.prototype.includes) Array.prototype.includes =function(value,start) {
    start=parseInt(start)||0;
    for(var i=start;i<this.length;i++) if(this[i]==value) return true;
    return false;
};
```

In deference to AuxTaco’s comment, here is a version of the polyfill which works for IE>8:

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(value,start) {
        start=parseInt(start)||0;
        for(var i=start;i<this.length;i++) if(this[i]==value) return true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The real `array.includes` is non-enumerable. Use `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: @AuxTaco Thanks for the comment. I have added a variation to the answer, though it does require IE>8.

Answer (score 1):

`in` doesn't function the same way in Javascript. You'll have to use multiple comparisons splitting them using the `||` (or `OR`) operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want useful set operation functions and dont mind adding a library, check out [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org)

Otherwise expect to write for loops to loop over values and perform equality checks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array

and use jquery.inArray() to check

read here for more http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score -1):

you can do that, nice and easy, store the values in an array and use `IN`

```
  var temparr = ['x', 'y', 'z', '0'];
     if (!$get('sslot_hf0').value in temparr) {
                $get('sslot_hf0').value = 'X';
            }
```

hope this helps

Comment: `'z' in ['x', 'y', 'z', '0']` returns false... Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) you have to specify a property name, not a value.